# i am trying to implement react-pdf in my web app

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-pdf

I am building a react web app project and i want it to be able to display pdfs from a link or local storage so I am using the library react-pdf  (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf)
here is my code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import SideNav from "./SideNav";
import UserBio from "./UserBio";
import "../CSS/Notes.css";
import { Document, Page } from "react-pdf";
import samplePdf from "../Web_Services_Hacking_and_Hardening.pdf";

function Notes() {
  const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState(null);
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);

  function onDocumentLoadSuccess({ numPages }) {
    setNumPages(numPages);
  }
  return (
    <div className="notes">
      <div className="notes__sideNav">
        <SideNav />
      </div>
      <div className="notes__main">
        <p>this is notes</p>

        
          <Document file={samplePdf} onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}>
            <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
          </Document>
        
        <p>
          Page {pageNumber} of {numPages}
        </p>
      </div>

      <div className="notes__userBio">
        <UserBio />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Notes;
```

Comment: OK, that is your code, and... what is the problem?

Comment: it displays failed to load pdf